# Dialogflow V2 | DetectIntent

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, google-apis-explorer

I am trying to use dialogflow API v2 to provide audio (base64string) directly to dialogflow instead of text.

URL : https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/projects/my_project_id/agent/sessions/12345:detectIntent

The Authentication Bearer content-type have been set correctly in the header.

Request :

```
{  
   "queryInput":{  
      "audioConfig":{
        "audioEncoding": "AUDIO_ENCODING_LINEAR_16",
        "sampleRateHertz": 16000,
        "languageCode":"en"

      }
   },
   "inputAudio":"SUQzBAAAAAAAI1RTU0UAAAA..."
}
```

I am getting success in response, however the response is incomplete.

```
{
    "queryResult": {
        "languageCode": "en"
    }
}
```

Additionally, the message does not show in Dialogflow history. Can anyone facing the same issue or having any idea/suggestion how to tackle this please help?

Ref : https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.sessions/detectIntent#request-body

Note: When using Text input instead of Audio, this works perfectly.

Comment: If you try to perform the same request at https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/dialogflow/dialogflow/v2/dialogflow.projects.agent.sessions.detectIntent, do you get the same incomplete response for the exact same base64 encoded audio string? Regarding the history, do you mean that none of the interactions are saved in history? If so, can you try to test the API through the API explorer and check if that was saved in history?

Comment: did we find any solution for this problem?. I am also facing this same issue

Comment: I have the same problem. Maybe it is a wrong audio encoding.